# UIDocumentInteractionController crashes on device for large images

Tags: iphone, ipad, quicklook

I use UIDocumentInteractionController for quick look on iPad (4.3.3).

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
self.doc = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
self.doc.delegate = self;
[self.doc presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

This works fine for all supported types and for jpg images up to (~ 2000x2000 px). Then I tried to quick view jpg image 6000x6000 px and got a crash with message:

```
[Switching to process 11779 thread 0x0]
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J3)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/DisplayBundles/Image.qldisplay/Image (file not found).
warning: No copy of Image.qldisplay/Image found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

Large images on emulator work fine. Quicklook.framework is in Build Phase. What's the reason?
Large Image size = 426Kb (compressed jpeg).

UPD: same story on iPad2

UPD2: I tried to use UIWebView instead, no crashes but no an ideal solution

Answer (score 1):

`UIDocumentInteractionController` crashes frequently with files of moderate size. As you are on 4.3.3, you could try the `QLPreviewController`.

Comment: still crashes on iPad and works on simulator. here is sample image http://cl.ly/9BJ4

Comment: QLPreviewController can be called the new UIDocumentInteractionController (introduced in 4.0). However, it is not crash free. That's the best you get on iOS.